# parameters are of unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to delete all rows in my table where the date is before or the same day as today, to update reservations in a hotel database.

```
dat_danas = datetime.datetime.today().date()
dat_danas.strftime("%d-%M-%Y")

conn = sqlite3.connect("rezervacije.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = "DELETE FROM infoGosti WHERE DATE(odl_fld) <= ?"
cursor.execute(query, dat_danas,)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: You have to reassign the return value: `dat_danas = dat_danas.strftime("%d-%M-%Y")`

Comment: The problem is `cursor.execute(query, dat_danas,)` should be `cursor.execute(query, (dat_danas,))` so that second argument is a tuple. You can skip braces when define tuple in assignment, but not here. @Matthias advise still stands.

Comment: @buran I didn't see that. I just saw the trailing comma and assumed everything was correct. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @buran thankyou, but still now quite sure how to delete the records in my db before today. I've also tried to delete with if statement but no success.

Comment: Can you provide [mre], i.e. incl. set-up code creating the tables in the db and populating some data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this example:

```py
import sqlite3, datetime

""" creating connection & table """
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') # creates db in Memory
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE store (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, validity DATE)''')
db.commit()

""" populating data """
stores = [
    ['Stock 1', '12.10.2021'],
    ['Stock 2', '17.04.2022'],
    ['Stock 3', '27.11.2022'],
    ['Stock 4', '23.09.2022'],
]
cursor.executemany('''INSERT INTO store (name, validity) VALUES (?,?)''', stores)
db.commit()

""" queries """
today = datetime.date.today().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM store """)    # result before deletion
db.commit()
res = cursor.fetchall()

query = """ DELETE FROM store WHERE validity < ? """
cursor.execute(query, (today,))
cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM store """)    # result after deletion
db.commit()
res = cursor.fetchall()
```